# How to match some nested structure with regex?

Tags: php, regex

For example, I have a string like this:

```
{% a %}
    {% b %}
    {% end %}
{% end %}
```

I want to get the content between `{% a %}` and `{% end %}`, which is  `{% b %} {% end %}`.
I used to use {% \S+ %}(.*){% end %} to do this. But when I add c in it:

```
 {% a %}
        {% b %}
        {% end %}
    {% end %}
{% c %}
{% end %}
```

It doesn't work...  How could I do this with regular expression?

Comment: Is it a nested structure of arbitrary depth? If so, that is not a regular language.

Comment: Please don't try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454

Comment: You will probably have a much easier time matching the individual elements with a regular expression and using a stack to match the opening / closing blocks.

Comment: @eldarethis: That is red herring, please stop repeating it. **IT DOES NOT APPLY** because it is absolutely trivial to match nested structures using modern patterns.

Comment: @casablanca: Please stop posting that idiotic and irrelevant link. It does not apply, and is wrong anyway.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Good thing that PHP regular expressions are not [REGULAR](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html#comment_40 "Modern regexes are NOT REGULAR, and haven't been for a long, long time!")!

Comment: @tchrist: That's why it was a comment and not an answer. I personally think that writing a parser is simpler and more understandable than a regex in such situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this test data:

```php
$text = '
{% a %}
    {% b %}
        {% a %}
        {% end %}
    {% end %}
        {% b %}
        {% end %}
{% end %}
{% c %}
{% end %}
';
```

This tested script does the trick:

```php
<?php
$re = '/
    # Match nested {% a %}{% b %}...{% end %}{% end %} structures.
    \{%[ ]\w[ ]%\}       # Opening delimiter.
    (?:                  # Group for contents alternatives.
      (?R)               # Either a nested recursive component,
    |                    # or non-recursive component stuff.
      [^{]*+             # {normal*} Zero or more non-{
      (?:                # Begin: "unrolling-the-loop"
        \{               # {special} Allow a { as long
        (?!              # as it is not the start of
          %[ ]\w[ ]%\}   # a new nested component, or
        | %[ ]end[ ]%\}  # the end of this component.
        )                # Ok to match { followed by
        [^{]*+           # more {normal*}. (See: MRE3!)
      )*+                # End {(special normal*)*} construct.
    )*+                  # Zero or more contents alternatives
    \{%[ ]end[ ]%\}      # Closing delimiter.
    /ix';
$count = preg_match_all($re, $text, $m);
if ($count) {
    printf("%d Matches:\n", $count);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        printf("\nMatch %d:\n%s\n", $i + 1, $m[0][$i]);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the output:

```
2 Matches:

Match 1:
{% a %}
    {% b %}
        {% a %}
        {% end %}
    {% end %}
        {% b %}
        {% end %}
{% end %}

Match 2:
{% c %}
{% end %}
```

**Edit:** If you need to match an opening tag having more than one word char, replace the two occurrences of the `\w` tokens with `(?!end)\w++`, (as is correctly implemented in tchrist's excellent answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo in Perl of an approach that works for your dataset. The same should work in PHP.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = <<'EO_STRING';
    {% a %}
            {% b %}
            {% end %}
        {% end %}
    {% c %}
    {% end %}
EO_STRING


print "MATCH: $&\n" while $string =~ m{
    \{ % \s+ (?!end) \w+ \s+ % \}
    (?: (?: (?! % \} | % \} ) . ) | (?R) )*
    \{ % \s+ end \s+ % \}
}xsg;
```

When run, that produces this:

```
MATCH: {% a %}
            {% b %}
            {% end %}
        {% end %}
MATCH: {% c %}
    {% end %}
```

There are several other ways to write that. You may have other constraints that you haven’t shown, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [recursive regex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).  PHP has support for it using `(?R)`.

I'm not familiar enough with it to be able to help you with the pattern itself, but hopefully this is a push in the right direction.